# grails plugin controlling load order

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

i've been looking several guidance about this in Grails official documentation site [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#understandingPluginLoadOrder)

but still i couldn't make it runs well.

Supposed i created two plugin. myplugin-a and myplugin-b .

Each plugin had their own bootstrap that will execute when main app which install those plugins runs. I had include this line of code in MypluginBGrailsPlugin.groovy

`def loadAfter = ['myplugin-a']`

but still the plugin runs the bootstrap on each plugins with the following order :

myplugin-b -> myplugin-a .

Did i miss something here ?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the camel-case syntax of the plugin name: `def loadAfter = ['mypluginA']`. See https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-hibernate-plugin/blob/master/HibernateGrailsPlugin.groovy for an example in the Hibernate plugin

Comment: still i couldn't make it runs as i want to. I used grails 2.0.0 and crate my plugin using syntax `create-plugin myplugin-plugina` and `create-plugin myplugin-pluginb`. I have change my `MypluginPluginaGrailsPlugin`section `def loadAfter = ['mypluginPlugina']` as suggested but still it wont run as i want it to. Note : the reason i want to put this thing in order is because i want the BootStrap on each plugin runs one after another.

Comment: Found the problem. I've uninstalled the plugin and reinstalling again it works. Still i couldn't figure out how to control the bootstrap load order. Any ideas on that ?